# Collect changes in a file every fixed time in node js

Tags: node.js, setinterval, chokidar

I have an external program that is streaming data to a csv file every now and then (but quit a lot).
I want to collect every 10 seconds all the **changed data** and do some processing on it.
means I want to process only lines I didn't processed before.

this is the basic code:

```
function myFunction() {

  var loop = setInterval(
    () =>
      {
          var instream = fs.createReadStream("rawData.csv"); //should somehow include only new data since last cycle
          var outstream = fs.createWriteStream("afterProcessing.csv");
          someProcessing(instream, outstream);
          outstream.on('finish', () => {
               sendBackResults("afterProcessing.csv");
                });
        //will exit the loop when 'run' flag will change to false
          if(!run) ? clearInterval(loop) : console.log(`\nStill Running...\n`) ;
      } , 10000 );    

 }
```

Now, I tried to work with chokidar and fs.watch but I couldn't figure out how to use them in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) can take a `start` parameter

> options can include start and end values to read a range of bytes from
>   the file instead of the entire file. Both start and end are inclusive
>   and start counting at 0

So you need to save the last position read, and use it on `start`.

You can get that using: `instream.bytesRead`.

```
let bytesRead = 0;

instream.on('end', () => {
  bytesRead = instream.bytesRead;
});
```

Comment: Clever solution @Marcos Casagrande, liked it very much. my problem now is that though the data is coming to the "rawData.csv" line by line, when I read it with the start parameter of bytes it doesn't continue with the next line but from a middle of a line. I also tried to put the bytesRead in an 'close' event and it's the same.

Comment: If it's starting from the middle of a line, it means it ended in the middle of a line, meaning that you starting reading when something was writing to it, you can try to offset that, calculating the beginning of the line.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "calculating the beginning of the line" ? How do I do that?